# How to schedule tasks on startup on a VPS while offline

Tags: automation, browser-automation

I Have a VPS that is scheduled to restart Several times.
On the start-up, i need to the browser to automatically run some simple tasks, like load a php script, clear history, change some simple random parameters.

I tried to accomplished this with auto clicker and macro creator programs like perfect automation , mouse recorder and a few others, and while it works fine, when I'm connected to the VPS, it does not work at all when i restart the machine, which is the objective of this problem: to full automate initial browser tasks on the machine start-up, without login.

Is there any fullproof software for this kind of stuff ? the time I'm wasting to try to accomplish this is becoming ridiculous